# How to run only a specific C++ gtest using BUCK

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googletest, buck

If I have tests like the following

```
TEST(One, A) { ... }
TEST(Two, B) { ... }
```

How can I only run `One.A` using `buck test`?  I would like to be able to do

```
buck test something -- --gtest_filter=One.A
```

But that does not seem to work.  Neither does `--include` or `--filter`

Answer (score 1):

So, as far as I know that's not supported directly by Buck. However, one thing you should be able to do is

`buck run //foo/bar:baz -- --gtest_filter=One.a`

This will give you the gtest gui, not the buck gui, but it should work. I'll open up an github issue (if we don't have one already) to see what it would take to get it integrated into the internal runner, since it's also a feature I've wanted for a while

Edit: https://github.com/facebook/buck/issues/1688